# How Can I display All products in one cms page in Magento 1?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, cms-pages

I am using Magento 1.9.3

There are 8000 products in my website and I want to display all of them in one cms page.

I have added below code in my cms page:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

But it didn't work. it displays only 9 products.

So what can I do to display all products in one cms page?

Comment: Go to Manage Category and make root Category to Is Anchor to “YES”

Comment: @Rohan Hapani I think it's not gonna work because I have created a separate cms page "All Products" and in this page I want to display all product.

Answer (score 0):

Create new category. Set this category include menu No.
Call phtml file from CMS page

```
{{block type="catalog/product" template="catalog/product/view/custom.phtml"}}
```

Now from that phtml load that category product.

```
$categoryId = 10; // Your newly created category id
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);

/**
 * Getting product collection for a particular category 
 */
$prodCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
            ->addCategoryFilter($category)
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*');


/** 
 * Printing category and products name
 */ 
echo '<strong>'.$category->getName().'</strong><br />';
foreach ($prodCollection as $val) {
    echo $val->getName() . '<br />';
}
```